# C++ ensure object exists while executing a function

Tags: c++, invariants, preconditions, lifetime-scoping

I have a function `foo`. During the execution of `foo`, I want to be certain that an object of type `Bar` exists. Let’s call whatever object that happens to be “`bar`.”

I cannot copy or move `bar`, and `bar` can have any storage duration. The one thing I do know about `bar` is that it is an empty object.

`foo` doesn't need to do anything with `bar` or know anything about it.

- First thought is, pass a `Bar&` into `foo` to tell the calling environment, *“hey, you need to make sure `bar` exists while I’m running!”* But the calling environment could pass a dangling reference into `foo`, in which case `bar` would be destroyed before `foo` runs.
- Second thought is, pass a `shared_ptr` to `bar` in. But (correct me if I’m wrong) this would require `bar` to have dynamic storage duration.
- Third thought is, write a helper type that *is* copyable and movable that guarantees the existence of `bar`. But this feels like reinventing the `shared_ptr` wheel.

What are my options for ensuring `bar` exists during `foo`, and what are their strengths and limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the calling environment could pass a dangling reference into foo

It really couldn't.  Dangling references are not legal, so the only way for this to happen is by the caller violating the language rules.  I don't find this a compelling concern.

> pass a shared_ptr to bar in. But this would require bar to have dynamic storage duration.

Not quite.  A shared_ptr can be constructed with a custom deleter, so if the caller wants to pass in a "stack allocated" `Bar`, they can construct a shared_ptr with a deleter which does not delete anything.

> bar is that it is an empty object

Then what's the point of the entire exercise?  Is it because the `Bar` constructor and/or destructor have side effects which must occur before/after `foo` runs?  If that's the case, maybe `foo` should just do those things itself, or a `foo_wrapper` function can be created to hide these details.

Comment: “Is it because the `Bar` constructor and/or destructor have side effects which must occur before/after `foo` runs?” Yes, `bar` owns a resource. Having `foo` do those things itself would require `foo` to know about `bar`.

Comment: @nebuch: It actually wouldn't.  For example you could have `foo` take a `std::function` which it calls when `bar`'s resource is no longer required.  The caller would then release the resource, and `foo` wouldn't know any details about it.